# Python: URL data to csv reader

Tags: python, csv, url, urllib

I'm trying to convert the results of a url request to a [CSV reader object](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html) in Python. The output seems fine but the following error occurs:

```
    for study_id, sample_id, run_id in reader:
ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 3, got 1)
```

First I request the data and convert it to string data:

```
req = urllib.request.Request(url=url_get_project_runs, headers={'Content-Type': 'text/plain'})
        res = urllib.request.urlopen(req)
        dec_res =  res.read().decode()
        sys.stderr.write(str(dec_res)) --> for the print see below
        return dec_res
```

The print will give this:

```
ERP001736,ERS494374,ERR598958
ERP001736,ERS494394,ERR598963
ERP001736,ERS494431,ERR598964
ERP001736,ERS494445,ERR599170
ERP001736,ERS494488,ERR598996
ERP001736,ERS494518,ERR598976
ERP001736,ERS494559,ERR598986
ERP001736,ERS494579,ERR599078
ERP001736,ERS494616,ERR598944
ERP001736,ERS494628,ERR599001
ERP001736,ERS488919,ERR1701760
```

This seems fine to me because the items are seperated by commas and the "rows"are intact.
However if I use this as input for the CSV reader and try to print the three columns, as here:

```
reader = csv.reader(dec_res, delimiter=',')
        for study_id, sample_id, run_id in reader:
            print(study_id + ", " + sample_id + ", " + run_id)
```

The following error will occur:
**`ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 3, got 1)`**

I further tested some code to find the problem:

```
 for row in reader:
            sys.stderr.write(str(row))
```

This will give:

```
['E']['R']['P']['0']['0']['1']['7']['3']['6']['', '']['E']['R']['S']['4']['7']...etc
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are passing `str` to the csv reader and it expects a line-by-line iterable. `str` is a character-by-character iterable. Wrap your string with `StringIO` or use `splitlines` (or any other means to provide line-by-line iterable).

```
import csv
from io import StringIO

dec_res = """ERP001736,ERS494374,ERR598958
ERP001736,ERS494394,ERR598963
ERP001736,ERS494431,ERR598964
ERP001736,ERS494445,ERR599170
ERP001736,ERS494488,ERR598996
ERP001736,ERS494518,ERR598976
ERP001736,ERS494559,ERR598986
ERP001736,ERS494579,ERR599078
ERP001736,ERS494616,ERR598944
ERP001736,ERS494628,ERR599001
ERP001736,ERS488919,ERR1701760"""

reader = csv.reader(StringIO(dec_res), delimiter=',')
#reader = csv.reader(dec_res.splitlines(), delimiter=',')

for study_id, sample_id, run_id in reader:
    print(study_id + ", " + sample_id + ", " + run_id)
```

Comment: Thankyou so much!

Comment: Actually csv can (not always) read normal strings if you pass them inside a list:
`
>>>data = csv.reader(['ERP001736,ERS494374,ERR598958'])
>>> list(data)
[['ERP001736', 'ERS494374', 'ERR598958']]
`

But @damians way is much better.